# $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ isomorph with $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ iff gcd(m,n)=1

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

I have to prove:

> $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ isomorph with $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ iff gcd(m,n)=1

Proof: Let them be isomorph. Every element in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ has order $m$ and in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ order $n$ and this order is maximal which means every element in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has maximal order of $\frac{mn}{gcd(m,n)}$. Since $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order $mn$ that must hold also for $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ which means $gcd=1$.
On the other hand it is enough to show the injectivity of the map $f$ which sends $z+mn\mathbb{Z}$ to $(z+m\mathbb{Z},z+n\mathbb{Z})$. To show that we must show that $kerf={0}$. If $a\in kerf$ then $(a+m\mathbb{Z},a+n\mathbb{Z})=(0,0)$ which is true only if $a=rm=sm$ for $r$ and $s$ integers. From which follows m divides a and n divides a and since they are coprime we have $a=0$(as equivalence classes).

Now I am pretty confused and I would not know how to explain following things from the proof:

The first thing I really don't understand is the following. Maybe it is some trivial idea or formula but I am clearly missing this.

> ..which means every element in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has maximal order of $\frac{mn}{gcd(m,n)}$

The second is the part with the $kerf$. We need to show that it is equal to zero but then at the moment we take $a$ in $kerf$ we then assume that the values that come are zeroes.

And why:

> which is true only if $a=rm=sm$ for $r$ and $s$ integers. From which follows m divides a and n divides a and since they are coprime we have $a=0$.

I am pretty new to Algebra so it might be that I am missing something which might be pretty straightforward but I would be very thankful for some help.

Comment: Not every element of $\Bbb Z/m \Bbb Z$ has order $m$. For example, when $m=6$, the order of $4+ 6\Bbb Z$ is $3$.

Comment: could you help me out how to correct it in order for the proof to be valid?

Comment: Isomorphism of groups or rings ? You have to be precise in your question. The map that send $1$ to $1$ may not be the unique group morphism.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking for Group,

if gcd(m,n) = 1, then lcm(m,n) =mn

1 has order m in Zm.
1 has order n in Zn.

(1,1) has order mn in Zm×Zn.

Now, if  order of Group G = order of an element in G
then, Group G must be cyclic.

Any Group of order mn must be isomorphic to Zmn .

Hence, Zm×Zn is isomorphic to Zmn when (GCD m,n = 1)

Hence, you will get an isomporphism spending 1-->(1,1)

Converse part is easy.
Hope you got it.

Comment: Please use Mathjax. ASCII art is terrible.

Answer (score -2):

**Question:** "I am pretty new to Algebra so it might be that I am missing something which might be pretty straightforward but I would be very thankful for some help."

**Answer:** There is a lemma called the "chinese remainder lemma" that might be helpful.
Let $R:=\mathbb{Z}$ and let $I:=(m), J:=(n) \subseteq R$ be the ideals generated by $m,n$. It follows $IJ$ is an ideal and there is an inclusion of ideals $IJ \subseteq I \cap J$. If $gcd(m,n)=1$ it follows there is an equailty of ideals $(m,n)=(1)$ and conversely if $(m,n)=(1)$ it follows $gcd(m,n)=1$. Hence $gcd(m,n)=1$ iff $(m,n)=(1)$. There is a canonical map of rings

$$\phi: R/IJ \rightarrow R/I \oplus R/J$$

defined by $\phi(x):=(x,x)$. By definition $ker(\phi)=I \cap J$.

**Claim 1:** If $(m,n)=(1)$ it follows $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

Since $(m,n)=(1)$ it follows (Atiyah-Macdonald, Prop 1.10) that $IJ=I\cap J$ hence $\phi$ is injective. By the same proposition it follows $\phi$ is surjective. The proof of the CRL is constructive and it is intstructive to read the proof.

**Claim 2:** If $\phi$ is an isomorphism it follows $(m,n)=(1)$.

There is an induced surjective map

$$\psi: R \rightarrow R/I\oplus R/J$$

and again by AM.Prop.1.10 it follows $(m),(n)$ are coprime hence $(m,n)=(1)$.

Hence $gcd(m,n)=1$ iff $\phi$ is an isomorphism.

The above referred to proposition is explicit and proves explicitly the above claims.